# For loop fetch array in php

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I want to delete mySQL rows with checkboxes. This is a code that should work according to someone on the internet, but some reason it doesn't for me. When I click delete it only refreshes but the row doesn't disappear. Has this something to do with my ID in the table?

```
<body>
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password="*****"; // Mysql password
$db_name="test"; // Database name
$tbl_name="deviation"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

?>
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="4" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Delete multiple rows in mysql</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Åtgärda</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Chassinummer</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Problem detail</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Fault code</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Position</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Help object</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Operation step</strong></td>
</tr>
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox"     id="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['chassi']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['problem_detail']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['fault_code']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['fault_code']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php  echo $rows['position']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['help_object']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['operation_step']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>

<tr>
<td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="delete"     type="submit"     id="delete" value="Delete"></td>
</tr>
<?php

**$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];**
**$delete = $_POST['delete'];**

// Check if delete button active, start this
if($delete){
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
$del_id = $checkbox[$i];

**$sql = "DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$del_id'";**
$result = mysql_query($sql);
}

// if successful redirect to delete_multiple.php
if($result){
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=deletetable.php\">";
}
}
mysql_close();
?>
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Print your resulting SQL query to see what you send to database. Instead of `echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=deletetable.php\">";` use `header('Location: deletetable.php')`, sanitize all user input or you in a risk

Comment: "someone on the internet" forgot to tell you about [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: That code is older than sin. There's deprecated `align` attributes, `mysql_*` functions, nonsensical double-asterisks... This is why you don't trust code from "someone on the Internet" and should always go through them with a fine-toothed comb (or better, write your own).

Answer (score 1):

There are certain things I want to direct your attention towards:

1) There are a number of lines in PHP enclosed in nonsensical double-asterisks. I'm shocked the PHP actually ran through those.

2) You have a `$result` defined within the global scope at the top of your script (where it was given a resource pointer from `mysql_query()`). This means that at the bottom, where you check for `if($result)`, that check will always come to `true` (unless there were syntactic errors). This also means that the page will always refresh when you click submit regardless of whether the deletion actually happened.

As I've mentioned in the comments, that code is (frankly speaking) a piece of crap. It's vulnerable to SQL injection, the code doesn't actually do what it's supposed to do, it's using deprecated attributes and functions... The failure of the code to do what you want isn't because of the IDs in your table, it's because of the broken, non-functioning code you copied off the Internet.

Answer (score -1):

Don't iterate over whole table
Replace this

```
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
$del_id = $checkbox[$i];

**$sql = "DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$del_id'";**
$result = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

with

```
if(isset($_POST['checkbox']) && is_array($_POST['checkbox')){
    foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $id){
        $id = (int)$id;
        $sql = "DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: But will be better if you rewrite that code from scratch. `mysql_*` is deprecated. I just trying to give you an idea how it may look like.

Comment: 1. he is not iterating over the whole table! he is iterating over the $checkbox array!

Comment: @Besnik If you look at how the code is generated, you'll see that both `for` and `foreach` in this case would have the same effect. -1 to you for not thinking through what the code should do.

Comment: @Besnik open your eyes and check from where he getting `$count`

Comment: @Palladium guess your comment adressed to me since it my answer :) If you'll take look at OP's code you'll see that he run `for` loop for `$count` records from the table. In my `foreach` I iterate only over `$_POST` array.

Comment: Nope, it was addressed to Besnik (hence the @Besnik at the beginning).

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov $count is from $result and $result he needs to display all the items - and look at the bottom: its a simple for-loop 0 - $count!

Comment: @Palladium ok, thought it was by mistake :)

Comment: @Palladium -1 to me for not thinking through what the code should do? What? Where i've wrote that the for and foreach loop dont have the same effect? Sorry, but i dont know what do you want to tell me

Comment: @Besnik He needs `$count` just to put it in `for` loop and if in `$_POST` variable with index `$i` is set - delete record, but that's wrong. That's why I wrote it in that way. In my code I delete only these records for which checkboxes are set.

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov Well, i see it but read the question again:
>> ... When I click delete it only refreshes but the row doesnt disapear ...

Comment: @Besnik its not disappear because he trying to delete row with wrong id.